# Modifying Dataframe based on Column Names and values in it

Tags: python

I have following dataframe

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -0.1 | 0 | 0.2 | 0 | 4 |
| 0 | 0 | -1 | -2 | 5 |

I would like an output as following based on A,B belong to category X and C,D,E belong to category Y -

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -cat X | 0 | +cat Y | 0 | +cat Y |
| 0 | 0 | -cat Y | -cat Y | +cat Y |

It basically checks the column name and assigns a category and checks the value to assign a sign. Is there any easy way to do this in Python? I am using COLAB, so probably have latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to just choose whatever columns you want and then perform check like below:

```
import numpy as np

for col in ['A','B']:
    df[col] = [x if x == 0 else '-Cat X' if x < 0 else '+ Cat X' for x in df[col]]

for col in ['C','D','E']:
    df[col] = [x if x == 0 else '-Cat Y' if x < 0 else '+ Cat Y' for x in df[col]]
```

This should produce the required result.

Comment: If there are many categories and many columns this would look very ugly, is there a way I can reference a dictionary and use X/Y as value of some variable(object)?

Comment: I suggest `np.select` then. It allows you to set multiple conditions  and their choices along with default values if required.https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html